# Re-open extensions welcome page VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes, when I install an extension, I accidently close the "welcome page" that is has. Recently, I downloaded settings sync on VS Code, but the `Welcome to Setting Sync` Page does not appear. How do I open it in order to configure everything? Even when I uninstall, reload, and re-download it, nothing appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to view the welcome page of an extension you can try searching for it in the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) by entering welcome or started. Searching by extension name may list everything available from the extension.